# Excel Formula SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for a little help with a formula in Excel I'm trying to get working.

The formula I'm using is: `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,P:P,"Food") - D2`.

I'd like to display the differences (in amounts) between the items labelled as "Food" vs "Non-Food" from column P.

What I'm currently getting is the following which I think is adding all three "Food" items divided by the amount:
[image]

I'm trying unsuccessfully to get it show like this, where it shows the difference in retone where Non-Food does not specifically match Food:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want MINIFS not SUMIFS or AVERAGEIFS

Comment: Yeah that kind of works but it isn't perfect. I'm realizing I'm going to have to rethink this. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi - struggling a little to follow - what does col D currently refer to / how was it calculated?  Your goal is to display the difference btwn food and non-food items.... ehem.. by row / that correspond to the same CAT_ID, overall? (overall its just sumifs(value, foodtype, "Food") - sumifs(...., "Non-Food")... but that can't be what you mean surely?  That's how I've interpreted though - pls expand on this point - its quite key to pinning this down given it seems to be your primary goal (I could fiddle on my calc to try to 'guess' how 84.99 relates to 25, but there are 10 other Qs - so some help

Comment: @JB-007 Hi! Column D is the retail for that item based on the CatID. Example: Pack 600044 in CatID YY is 84.99 while Pack 600044 in CatID is 85.99. I'm trying to setup a formula that looks at the Pack and then compare all the Food vs Non Food retails and give me the differences. So in this particular example YY which is a food CatID is 84.99 and JM which is a non food CatID is 85.99 so column E will show that there is a 1 dollar difference between the two. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this - it helps - I guess I must make the assumption that food items with the same 'packet id' have the same cost, and likewise for non-food items (if not, then the closest thing to a reasonable solution would be deducting from each price the average of cost of the food items in the same packet - this would give the desired result if so too)... see my soln below and let me know if I'm still not 'getting it' - thanks ! vote up/down accordingly for the benefit of future viewers..  Br,

Comment: PS - RE " I think is adding all three "Food" items divided by the amount:" is highly unlikely because your function does not have any divided by sign - it's doing exactly what it says - i.e. its summing the values corresponding to food type and deducting D2.

*recommendations: state whether cost is same across food types in same packet (and likewise/otherwise for non-food); and that you're only intereted in cost differences within same packet (not obvious from the filter and range of cells you've considered) - fyi - unable to make these changes as editing locked due to below solution*

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1** *(most likely | main)*:

- Identical cost for Food (F) in the same packet and likewise for Non-Food (NF)

(customize function as required)...

```
=D3:D12-AVERAGEIFS(D3:D12,C3:C12,"F",B3:B12,B3:B12)
```

[image: sample illustration]

*notes/comments:*

- *even if costs are not identical across food types of common packet (or likewise, across non-food types) - then this would still give a viable indication as to the average difference*

---

**Scenario 2** *(unlikely but possible)*

1. Cost is *not* identical across all food/non-food types belonging to the same packet
2. Average difference *won't do*
3. Only interested in *unique* differences (*otherwise remove 'unique' in fn below*)

*Requires Office 365 compatibility.*

```
=LET(x_,D3-FILTER($D$3:$D$12,--($B$3:$B$12=B3)*($C$3:$C$12="F")*($A$3:$A$12<>A3)),y_,FILTER($A$3:$A$12,--($B$3:$B$12=B3)*($C$3:$C$12="F")*($A$3:$A$12<>A3)),z_,UNIQUE(x_),zb_,INDEX(y_,MATCH(z_,x_,0)),TEXTJOIN(",",1,TEXT(SORT(z_),"£#0.00")&" ("&A3&"-"&INDEX(SORTBY(zb_,z_),0,1)&")"))
```

[image: super-fun fn ☺]

*(note: sorts unique differences in ascending order)*

---